# Dynamic add element to the top of the page

Tags: mongodb, meteor

**PROBLEM:** I have table with tr that have data from table, When I insert element in Mongo and post it on my page, element added on the bottom of the table

```
    Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

    Meteor.publish('allPosts', function(){
        return Posts.find({}, { sort: { date: -1 }} );
    });

    Meteor.subscribe("allPosts");

    Posts.insert({
      date: 1
    })

    Posts.insert({
      date: 2
    })

Posts.insert({
      date: 3
    })
<table class=" table">
      {{#each posts}}
          {{> postJobs}}
      {{/each}}
</table>

<template name="postJobs">
  <tr class="smallInfo">
    <td>{{date}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

In DOM I have:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td> // must be 3
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td> // must be 2
      </tr>
<tr>
        <td>3</td> // must be 1
      </tr>
    </table>
```

All my last inserts must add to the top of my page (table)

**EDIT :**
My problem with dynamic insert in collection (and i know about *-1* gramatik mistake) 
**EXAMPLE :**

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.setTimeout(function(){Test("10");}, 1000);
  function Test(x)
{
  Posts.insert( {
    submitDate: moment().format()
  });
}
  Meteor.setTimeout(function(){Test("10");}, 10000);
```

If i sort by submitDate it will show like :

```
<tr><td>10-10-10</td></tr> // must be 10-10-20
<tr><td>10-10-20</td></tr> // must be 10-10-10
```

**BUT** when i refresh my page(F5) all ok

```
<tr><td>10-10-20</td></tr> 
<tr><td>10-10-10</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not sort descending?

{sort: { date: -1 } }

Cheers,
Tom

UPDATE:

You can find a live example at a MeteorPad I prepared:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/Ba5DTe94NjFi3ZTPA/Playground_Flow-Router_Chat

You have to do the sort on the client side not within the publish method.

This is why you get first time sorted but then just as inserted returns.

If you do the sort on client side `find()` the minimongo will do it on each new document.

Hope this helps for you.
Tom

Comment: this is the right answer for sure. If you have opposite results with sorting: 1, you try -1 and check the results. Even if you don't understand how it works

Comment: It is work when I have collection with posts, but when i try to insert elements in collection and after that automatic publish them, they dont sorts